# c# remove duplicates for custom list

Tags: c#

Hello I have one string like

```
BRC CORP---BRC SME,BRC SME---BRC CORP,Confirmation of Customer Contact,Confirmation of Suitability Check,Consent,Driver's License---National Id Card,National Id Card---Driver's License,Residence certificate
```

now I need to convert this to list below.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

try
{
    string  mondantory_docs=Batch.Properties.Get("MissingDocCheck");
    List<string> result = mondantory_docs.Split(',').ToList();

}
catch
{
}
```

But I have one problem that I cant find a way. `BRC CORP---BRC SME`  and `BRC SME---BRC CORP` are normally same. so I need to remove one of them from list. as result I want below.

```
BRC CORP---BRC SME,Confirmation of Customer Contact,Confirmation of Suitability Check,Consent,Driver's License---National Id Card,Residence certificate
```

How can I remove this kind of duplicate from list

Thanks

Kind Regards

Comment: you can try to split such elements by `---` and check if each array contains elements of other array

Comment: How BRC CORP---BRC SME and BRC SME---BRC CORP are same?

Comment: One is exact another is optional choose if there is --- inside string.  @viveknuna

Comment: @core_user but order us different, right ?

Comment: maybe remove one of them before splitting your string :
mondantory_docs=mondantory_docs.Replace("BRC CORP---BRC SME","");

Answer (score 1):

After splitting the string, instead adding it to a list, add it to a HashSet. Then convert it to list. This should remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

There are bound to be many ways to do this, so I fully expect a range of answers here..

How about we zip through the list, and for any that have "---" inside, we split on "---", sort the bits we get and restore it, Then we can just get the distinct bits

```
string  mondantory_docs=Batch.Properties.Get("MissingDocCheck");
var result = mondantory_docs.Split(',');

var unique = result
  .Select(s => s.Contains("---") ? string.Join("---", s.Split("---").OrderBy(x=>x)) : s)
  .Distinct()
  .ToList()
```

(Answering based off a sole example is tricky; post more examples if you have them)

Comment: I've fixed the code, thank you for pointing out the part I didn't notice about the Driver's Licence

Comment: Thank you for your update. I am learning from your code how to use Linq properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MoreLinq Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) and use IEnumerable.DistinctBy(str => str).

This method will return a list of unique objects, For Example:

```
var list = new List<String>{"AB","BC","CB","AB","BA","BC","CB","AB" };
var distinctObjects = list.DistinctBy(ch => ch).ToList();
```

The distinctObjects will contain 4 objects: {AB, BC, CB, BA}.

Comment: reread the question, this will not work.

Comment: There should be a custom Compare method for this specific matter.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way could be to loop through the elements and maintain a dictionary to restrict duplicates. Check if any string contains *---* and any of the pair value is present in our dictionary,if yes skip the string from our unique list otherwise add the pair to dictionary.
By pair, I mean A---B is pair(A,B).

Code will go like this -

```
List<string> result = mondantory_docs.Split(",").ToList();
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new();
List<string> unique = new();
foreach (var doc in result)
{
    if (doc.Contains("---"))
    {
        var pair = doc.Split("---").ToList();
        if (dict.ContainsKey(pair[0]) || dict.ContainsKey(pair[1]))
            continue;
        else
            dict.Add(pair[0], pair[1]);
    }
    unique.Add(doc);
}
```

Comment: If follow your code, the easiest way would be just  string.Replace("BRC SME---BRC CORP,", "");

Comment: I considered different possible scenarios, not the specific string mentioned in the question. There can be possibilities like there is no duplicates or multiple duplicates and we don't know which of the two strings is forming a duplicate.
Ex. "BRC CORP---BRC SME,BRC SME---BRC CORP,BRC SME---BRC CORP,BRC CORP---BRC SME,.." On top that this snippet will run in a single loop and cover mostly all the cases.

Comment: Pls, check comments  of  CaiusJard answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I misunderstood the question. I've updated my code with a similar logic.